# Record limit in Mongo DB query

Tags: php, mongodb

How to limit records using Mongo DB query. This is my query, I need to limit only one record.

```
$this->referral->find()->skip(0)->limit(1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only one record use [findOne](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) function instead of find

I don't know php but I adapted your query to findOne() function.

```
$this->referral->findOne()->skip(0);
```